# Creat columns and rows from random.randint

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code currently. I am trying to have the list of 100 be in cols=20 and rows=5. I just can’t figure out how to do the columns/rows part. I also need to make sure it goes from largest to smallest.

```py
import random

def main():
    list_A = [random.randint(1,100) for num in range (100)]
    list_A.sort(reverse=True)

    print(list_A)
```

Comment: Do you know about list of lists?

Comment: No I do not. I’m in school right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach 1: Using a loop and list slicing

You already have built the list of 100 random numbers sorted in non-increasing order. Now, loop over the 5 rows, and use Python list slices to slice the 20 columns for each of the rows. For each of these rows, print the row on its own line.

```py
import random

list_A = [random.randint(1,100) for num in range (100)]
list_A.sort(reverse=True)

for i in range(5):
    row = list_A[i*20:i*20+20]
    print(row)
```

### Approach 2: Using `numpy.reshape`

If you are fine with installing [packages](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/) you could use `numpy` since it has a [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function.

```py
import random
import numpy as np

nums = np.array(list_A).reshape(5, 20).tolist()
for row in nums:
    print(row)
```

Comment: This is what it gives me:

Comment: This is what it gives me….   I need each row on its own line.  
[[99, 99, 99, 98, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 96, 96, 9
6, 94, 94, 93, 93, 92, 92, 90, 90], [90, 89, 89
, 87, 87, 86, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 80, 78, 77, 7
6, 73, 72, 72, 72, 69], [69, 69, 67, 66, 65, 64
, 64, 63, 62, 62, 61, 60, 59, 57, 52, 51, 51, 5
1, 49, 47], [47, 46, 44, 43, 42, 36, 35, 35, 34
, 34, 32, 30, 30, 29, 29, 28, 25, 23, 23, 23], 
[23, 22, 21, 18, 17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 11, 11, 10
, 9, 7, 7, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1]]

Comment: Sure, no problem, I updated the examples above to print each row on its own line.

Comment: Hmm…now it’s only giving me one row. I’m using approach 1.

Comment: Can you refresh the browser? You might not have the latest edits. The output I get has 5 rows.

Comment: It works! Forgot to indent the print. :) One last question. In the output the results have []. Can I remove those?

Comment: Sure, you can use the join command. In the print statement, instead of printing the row (which is a list of numbers), you can convert it to a string: `row_string = ", ".join(str(num) for num in row)`. Then `print(row_string)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested list comprehensions to create a list of lists.

```
>>> [
...   [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(20)]
...   for _ in range(5)
... ]
[[32, 41, 25, 93, 91, 49, 14, 74, 23, 46, 27, 60, 4, 17, 3, 36, 22, 5, 62, 6], 
 [68, 24, 48, 19, 32, 48, 41, 6, 80, 87, 15, 95, 15, 60, 22, 84, 61, 93, 38, 18], 
 [43, 20, 19, 95, 94, 13, 51, 24, 19, 9, 37, 12, 98, 92, 95, 94, 68, 79, 19, 40], 
 [20, 28, 79, 32, 95, 84, 85, 74, 47, 100, 39, 57, 42, 82, 10, 62, 93, 65, 14, 84], 
 [47, 16, 1, 19, 99, 20, 75, 90, 38, 87, 88, 82, 5, 14, 10, 34, 81, 82, 13, 96]]
>>>
```

It's then quite straightforward to have those sorted.

```
>>> [
...   sorted(
...     [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(20)], 
...     reverse=True
...   )
...   for _ in range(5)
... ]
[[99, 98, 98, 97, 93, 92, 91, 84, 62, 59, 53, 50, 48, 40, 38, 36, 32, 30, 28, 11], 
 [95, 94, 94, 83, 81, 66, 66, 63, 58, 45, 38, 38, 36, 35, 22, 18, 16, 11, 11, 3], 
 [99, 97, 97, 90, 86, 82, 79, 76, 64, 50, 47, 43, 41, 37, 35, 27, 27, 18, 2, 2], 
 [95, 94, 92, 91, 86, 85, 81, 76, 62, 61, 60, 54, 47, 34, 27, 20, 18, 16, 12, 11], 
 [96, 95, 84, 80, 77, 72, 66, 62, 58, 58, 54, 54, 44, 39, 28, 18, 15, 12, 8, 1]]
>>>
```